# Extract part of a string between point A and B

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to extract something from an email. The general format of the email will always be:

```
blablablablabllabla hello my friend.

[what I want]

Goodbye my friend blablablabla
```

Now I did:

```
                    string.LastIndexOf("hello my friend");
                    string.IndexOf("Goodbye my friend");
```

This will give me a point before it starts, and a point after it starts. What method can I use for this? I found:

```
String.Substring(Int32, Int32)
```

But this only takes the start position.

What can I use?

Comment: What happens if the email starts with "Goodbye my friend" and ends with "hello my friend" or nothing at all? Are you sure that this is a viable approach?

Comment: Yes I am sure, it is an automatic email. It will always be sent like this. Plus my program will read from a definition file, I can always change the strings.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Substring takes the start index (zero-based) and the number of characters you want to copy.

You'll need to do some math, like this:

```
string email = "Bla bla hello my friend THIS IS THE STUFF I WANTGoodbye my friend";
int startPos = email.LastIndexOf("hello my friend") + "hello my friend".Length + 1;
int length = email.IndexOf("Goodbye my friend") - startPos;
string sub = email.Substring(startPos, length);
```

You probably want to put the string constants in a `const string`.

Comment: Hi, thanks, this will work. However, there is no need to add the string after the LastIndexOf method, because this gives you the last position already. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, you do need to add it... unless you also want "hello my friend" in the output.  Try it... I did.

Comment: You are right, but why does this happen? email.LastIndexOf("hello my friend") wouldnt this give the index of the character after "friend"?

Comment: No, it gives the index in the original string corresponding to the beginning of the match string, not the end of the match string.

Comment: So what is the difference between indexOf and LastIndexOf? 

Edit: Oh now I get it, LastIndexOf simply starts from the end instead of the beginning.

Answer (score 14):

you can also use Regex

```
string s =  Regex.Match(yourinput,
                        @"hello my friend(.+)Goodbye my friend", 
                        RegexOptions.Singleline)
            .Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: RegEx can be quite slow compared to direct string manipulation. Not sure if it matters to the OP or not.

Comment: Never been a fan of regex... mainly because I don't know how to use it. Can you explain how that forumla works?

Comment: @TheGateKeeper it finds all characters `(.+)` between `hello my friend` and `Goodbye my friend`. Paranthesis are for getting the matched chars in group[1] (not the whole string hello.......friend)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply calculate the length from the start and end

```
const string startText = "hello my friend";
var start = str.LastIndexOf(startText) + startText.Length;
var end = str.IndexOf("Goodbye my friend");
var length = end -start;
str.Substring(start,length);
```

Comment: You need to account for the length of "hello my friend" too.  Your code will also grab that marker phrase.

Comment: Thanks, similar to first answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
string s1 = "find a string between within a lengthy string";
string s2 = s1.IndexOf("between").ToString();
string output = s1.Substring(0, int.Parse(s2));
Console.WriteLine("string before between is : {0}", output);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

You guys.. You only need to create a new Function by yourself.
Here, Use my code.

```
public string subsequence(string s, int start, int end) {
       string startstring = s.Substring(start);
       string endstring = s.Substring(end);
       startstring = startstring.Replace(endstring, "");
       return startstring;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

try `myStr.substring(start,end);`

Comment: What? I just listed that in the question. That method takes the start and the length, not start and the end.

Comment: from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):    
     substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) 
     Returns a new string that is a substring of this string.

And I thought you were talking about a static function from String, not the instance method, sorry.